# If we have a graph consisting of the vertices of spanning trees of a connected undirected graph that differ by one edge, prove that it is connected?

Tags: graph-theory

Suppose $G$ is a connected undirected graph. We say that two spanning trees $T$ and $T_1$ of $G$
are dif1 if and only if $T$ contains exactly one edge that is not in $T_1$

Now, we define the undirected graph $H$ as follows:

• $V(H)$, the set of vertices of $H$, is the set of all spanning trees of $G$, and

• $E(H)$, the set of edges of $H$, is the set of all $(T, T_1
)$ such that the spanning trees $T$ and $T
_1$ of
$G$ are dif1.

Prove that $H$ is connected.

Answer (score 2):

Take any two spanning trees $T$ and $T'$. As long as $T' \neq T$, do:

1. pick one edge in $T \backslash T'$ and add it to $T'$ (this will result in a cycle)
2. this cycle necessarily contains an edge not in $T$ (o/w $T$ would contain a cycle), remove this edge

Every iteration adds at most 1 edge from $T$ to $T'$, and hence corresponds to an edge in $H$. After at most $n-1$ iterations the tree $T'$ is transformed into $T$, proving that $H$ is connected.

Comment: Would this work for set of all one off spanning trees though?

Comment: I don't understand your question. What do you mean by "one off spanning trees"?